# Lightning console - error in $A.getCallback() when saving Case changes

Tags: lightning, error, service-cloud-console

In the past week or so, every time we are saving a change in Case within the Lightning Service Console, the following error is thrown 3-4 times:

[image]

I've tried removing few components from the Case page, without any luck. Did anyone experience the same?

Comment: I've seen this myself too recently. Is this happening to a specific type of browser or version? IE, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc.

Comment: We are still facing this issue. Doesn't seem to be browser dependent. Also, I make numerous attempts to remove Lightning Components from our page without any luck. So far, I wasn't able to find any new information online. That's a bummer.